# How to invoke REST api with xml body

Tags: java, xml, rest

I have a REST api ( https://localhost/server/api/login) for login which accept the parameters in xml format as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Request xmlns="http://www.xxxx.com/center/cbm/1.0.0">
  <Users>
    <User>
      <Type>userType</Type> 
      <Name>admin</Name> 
      <Password>password</Password> 
      <Captcha>On</Captcha> 
    </User>
   </Users>
 </Request>
```

How can I invoke same with Java and receive response.

Comment: just post the data use HttpClient or URLConnection

Comment: The following may help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html

Answer (score 3):

You can do a HTTP POST request using [Apache HTTP Client 4.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html):

```
String xmlString = "... your data ..."

HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost("https://localhost/server/api/login");
httpRequest.setEntity(new StringEntity(xmlString));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpRequest, new BasicHttpContext());

if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK && httpResponse.getEntity() != null) {
  //handle response ok
} else {
  //handle error
}
```